# conv1D kernel size in Keras

Tags: keras, convolution

I have created and trained neural network using several Conv1D layers. My input has size 125x3. I am using the same kernel sizes for each Conv1D layers. I tried several kernel sizes 2, 5, 25, 50 and even 125 and I am using "same" padding. It was unexpected for me that Keras worked with kernel size equal to the input size. And even more unexpected that kernel size of 126 is also worked. Example of the architecture with kernel size 126 which is bigger then input size:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(125,3),dtype='float32')
out1 = Conv1D(20,126,padding='same',activation='relu')(inputs)
out1=BatchNormalization(name='BatchNormalization0')(out1)
out1 = Conv1D(112,126,padding='same',name='Conv1',activation='relu')(out1)
out1=BatchNormalization(name='BatchNormalization1')(out1)
```

I can't understand why it works. Could someone please explain what happens in Keras when I am using kernel size equal to input size or even bigger than input size?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

## How can the kernel size be larger than the time steps ?

Let's take a look at your second line

```
out1 = Conv1D(20,126,padding='same',activation='relu')(inputs)
```

This is creating a convolution the outputs 20 filters and uses a kernel of 126, and most importantly has padding set to **same**!.  That padding means to put enough zeros at the beginning and end of your time series so that after the convolution the output time steps is equal to the input time steps.

If the input time steps was 10, and the kernel was 5, then we would have to add 2 zeros at the start and end of the data.

In your case, with a kernel of 126, there will be 62 zeros added to the beginning and 63 added to the end of your data prior to the convolution.

- Input shape is 125x3
- 'same' padding added to make it 250x3
- apply a 20 filter 126 kernel on 250x3 resulting in 125x20 output

Basically, you are doing a convolution on a bunch of zeros.